# How to trigger a shell script on a Google compute Engine when a new file is uploaded to cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm building a program that processes csv files and extracts data from them using a shell script whenever a user uploads the file to a google storage bucket. Users can upload files any number of times in a day and they have to be processed immediately. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Cron Job](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/) and run the script in regular time interval or every minute if you like. To check if new file is upload and process the csv files to extract data using the shell script you have created.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the program that will be processing the csv files on a Linux machine you can do this:

1. [Create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) a IAM user to get access to the  bucket with the csv.
2. [Install](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) the gsutil on your linux and configure the access with the [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles)
   user.
3. Create a shell script using the gsutil  rsync command like, [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) the documentation.

   gsutil rsync -d -r bucket local_dir
4. With this command you can synchronize a bucket with a local folder and viceversa, so only the new files will be downloaded, you can do this every minute or wherever you want.
5. Process the new cvs files